# Swing application - Jtextfield not able to display copy/pasted regional charcters

Tags: java, utf-8, jtextfield

I have a swing application which converts from UTF-8 stirng to hex characters.When i copy/paste some regional language(like  Kannda,Telugu,Tamil etc) characters into the JTextField, it is showing boxes

Answer (score 0):

Oracle had an answer as follows.

```
JTextField txtField = new JTextField(txtField.setDocument(new DefaultStyledDocument());
```

Try this.